# Mobile: Better GPS accuracy - Sensor VS. Google Maps provided location

Tags: google-maps, mobile, gps, geolocation, gis

**Info**: GPS on mobile devices has limitation and roughly we are talking up to 10-30m accuracy.

**Solution**: GIS professionals (e.g. Google Maps) applying variety of techniques to overcome this challenge. For example: When the sensor telling you are at location that corresponds to a building - That's impossible (GPS needs clear sky view), so they automatically align you with the nearest road. There are many such well known GIS techniques.

**Question**: If I need the best GPS accuracy - What is my alternative?

1. Raw sensor data.
2. Use Google Maps API & retrieve the location from them. Does this means I benefits from Google Maps GIS smart processing like mentioned above?
3. Implement my own GIS algorithms.

In this scope I'm interested to know what methods other experienced mobile developers applying in order to get *real* accurate GPS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Google's Fused Location API if you do not want to develop everything from scratch.

*Fused Location Provider analyses GPS, Cellular and Wi-Fi network location data in order to provide the highest accuracy data. Also, this provider uses different device sensors to define if a user is walking, riding a bicycle, driving a car or just standing in order to adjust the frequency of location updates.*

*Fused location provider can be used to get periodic location updates (Google provides us with the perfect [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) on this, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel). It can notify us when a user is entering/leaving some area (this feature is called geofencing. More information about implementation details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)). What’s more, using geofencing an application can track up to 100 targets. In fact, geofencing uses cellular location data to avoid tracking distant targets (there is no point in tracking proximity to target which is 100 miles away using expensive GPS if we can use cellular location, which gives 0.7-1.5 miles’ accuracy).*

Answer (score 1):

To get best GPS, just make sure than no WLAN, or cell tower location mode is enabled.
This can be set in ios and android.

A modern GNSS chip evaluates both, the US GPS and the russian GLONASS system.
This will give a location acuracy of about 2-3m in location where GPS correction (=SBAS) is enabled (WAAS in US, EGNOS in Europe). (Others in India and China)

Countries that do not have such an SBAS correction have less acurate receivement. It drops to 6-10m.

In dense cities it still can happen to have 30m deviation, but this does not happen often.

There is absolutley no need to use Google Maps Api, if you are not interested in indoor locations and if you have GPS enabled.  Each GPS location has an quality value attached (called horicontalAccuracy). You can use that to filter for your needs.

Further filtering is always application dependent, even withing the application different filterings apply to different tasks.

E.g an distance caluclation would use another filtering than a map display.
At the map you want the locations immedeatly to know where you are, even if the location is a bit distorted.
For distance calculations you can use another type of filtering which avoid, e.g outliers.
If you have to provide location to other servers/ instances, etc, The (nearly) unfiltered locations are often the best. (The receiver can use his own filtering)